# Detect Bluetooth Keyboard's "Enter" key press using UIKeyCommand

Tags: swift

Detect Bluetooth Keyboard's "Enter" key press using UIKeyCommand

I am using UIKeyCommand without modifiers to detect key presses of certain characters. For instance, when a user with an iPad + Bluetooth Keyboard presses the backspace key, an action occurs.

Here's the code for that:

```
UIKeyCommand(input: "\u{8}", modifierFlags: [], action: "Backspace:")
```

I am trying to make something happen when the user presses the enter key. I do not know the code for the enter key.

Backspace is `"\u{8}"`, but what is return?

**Answer (thanks Craig): enter is "\r", see question that this is a duplicate of.**

Comment: @CraigOtis Yes, that helps, thanks! I hadn't found that before even after lots of googling.